# Create a standalone html page which shows the contents of all files within a folder

Tags: html, file-io

I have the following folder structure:

```
index.html
my_folder
    |-- file1.txt
    |-- file2.txt
    |-- another_file.txt
    |-- ...
```

Within `index.html`, I want to show the first line of each file within the folder `my_folder` and list it in a html table.

Is there an easy way to do this? It should work on all computers accessing the folder, which don't have php or whatever running.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Local webpages have no ability to read the directory structure of the folder they are in. (Imagine the security implications if that was possible and you double clicked an HTML file attached to an email).

If you were running an HTTP server, then you could use server side code (or even basic directory listing pages that most servers generated automatically) to list the files in a format accessible to JavaScript.

Comment: Too bad, I wished that there was a standalone solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in HTML or JavaScript for security reasons

However you can type this into your browser to view a local directory
"file:///C:/users//desktop/"

Answer (score 0):

As written above, what I originally wanted is apparently impossible.
To round up things, here is how I circumvented the problem:

The key is to change the folder structure into something deterministic. I chose:

```
index.html
    |-- 0/
        |-- info.txt
        |-- ...
    |-- 1/
        |-- info.txt
        |-- ...
    |-- 2/
        |-- info.txt
        |-- ...
    |-- ...
```

Then, I can read my files using `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
<script>
var rawFile = [];
// 1000 is much larger than the total number of files
for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var folderPath = "./" + i;
    rawFile[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile[i].open("GET", folderPath + "/info.txt", false);
    rawFile[i].onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile[i].readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile[i].status === 200 || rawFile[i].status == 0)
            {
                var data = rawFile[i].responseText;
                // do some formatting
                $("table").append(data);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile[i].send(null);
}
</script>
```

Probably not the cleanest way to do it and definitely quite inflexible, but it works.